# Is there a cheap way to achieve this 'bubble film' look

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders

I'm new to Blender, having basically only just completed the donut tutorial. I'm making some diagrams for a scientific presentation, which look like this:

[image]

I'm reasonably happy with how this looks, but I'm wondering if my method is overkill. To create those bubble-like surfaces I'm doing this:

- create a cylinder with about 16 vertices around the circumference, delete the end faces, and add a subdivision modifier
- then apply a thickness modifier to turn it into a really thin sheet
- in the material, set the transmission to 100%, roughness to 0, and add a volume absorption node. Adjust colour and density of the absorption node to get the colour right, and adjust the index of refraction to change the intensity of reflections.

This looks good, but my thought is that it's simulating the light refracting and bouncing around inside the layer of glass, even though it's so thin you can't really see it. My render times aren't excessive, but I'm rendering on CPU and it would be good to keep them as low as possible, so I'm wondering if there's a cheaper way to achieve the same look.

TL;DR is there a way to 'fake' this look more cheaply than modelling the surfaces as thin layers of glass?

For bonus points, I'd really like to get the background to be pure white, but if I brighten it up too much it's hard to get the bubble surfaces to look good. This is probably a separate issue, but I mention it just in case there's a way to kill both birds with one stone. (The background is currently part of the sky, which is the only lighting in the scene.)

Comment: TBH, using only Absorption and not Scatter, volumes are not actually that heavyweight (since the renderer only has to measure the distance travelled through the volume, rather than trace multiple scatter rays for each small step) - so the method you're using shouldn't be too inefficient. There would be methods of faking it with Fresnel but then you'll potentially lose some realism.

Comment: There are no bonus points here. Ask just one question per post. Create as many posts as questions you have.

Comment: @susu as you know, I did ask a separate question for that point. But as I wrote in this question, I mentioned it here in case there was a way to solve both problems simultaneously.

Comment: The idea is that someone looking for an answer on how to make pure white doesn't have to search for "bubble"

Comment: @susu yes, I know that. I'm new to this site but I'm a very experienced Stack Exchange user. As I said, (1) I did in fact ask a different question about the white background, so that's not an issue at all, and (2) I mentioned it here in case there was a way to fake the bubble texture that would also, simultaneously, fake the white background in a satisfactory way. Aside from repeating these points a third time, I am not sure how I can make them clearer.

Comment: Just to set your mind at rest, I promise that if someone posts an answer here that's relevant to the other, more general, white background question, I will post a self-answer there containing the same information.